# Waiting for IDBCursor.onsuccess to complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, indexeddb

I have an IndexedDB containing properties of various elements on the page.  I have an index on one of those properties and I use a key range to get a specific list of results.

```
var key = IDBKeyRange.bound(10, 20);
var cursor = store.index('property').openCursor(key);
```

The problem I have is with the `cursor.onsuccess` function.  It seems to execute for each result in the result set.  Consequently, I can't execute a callback function once all of the results have been parsed.

```
cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var cursor = e.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        if (cursor.value.prop1 > 30 && cursor.value.prop2 < 80) {
            // Do stuff with result
            someArray.push({
                prop1: cursor.value.prop1,
                prop2: cursor.value.prop2
            }):
        }
    }
    cursor.continue();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safest way to know that your action is finished is to use the transaction on complete event. This event is triggered after the cursor is closed.

```
transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
    console.log('transaction completed');
};
```

Also to be sure that no error occurred add event listener to transaction events on error and on abort.

```
transaction.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log('transaction error');
};

transaction.onabort = function (event) {
    console.log('transaction abort');
};
```

Comment: I tried this initially, but `cursor.oncomplete` never fires (at least in Chrome 23.0.1271.26)

Comment: cursor object doesn't have on complete event, you should bind this event to transaction object.

Comment: I guess I don't understand... The variable `cursor` represents the transaction `openCursor()`...  I don't know what else I'd bind an `oncomplete` function to...

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/#toc-step4
first you open a database, second you open a transaction a third you open cursor on that transaction that's how stuff in indexed db without using any api works

Comment: Ohhhh! I understand.. Sorry, it's been a long day.  Yes, transaction.oncomplete fires just fine. I don't know why someone downvoted your answer, though. :-/  I'll upvote it for you.

Comment: I wonder why the `cursor.onsuccess` function fires one last time then?

Comment: last time cursor.onsuccess is fired with empty result field however that event should fire before transaction.oncomplete

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, `cursor.onsuccess` fires one last time with `e.target.result` undefined.  You can execute a callback function when this happens:

```
cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var cursor = e.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        if (cursor.value.prop1 > 30 && cursor.value.prop2 < 80) {
            // Do stuff with result
            someArray.push({
                prop1: cursor.value.prop1,
                prop2: cursor.value.prop2
            }):
        }
    } else {
        // Execute code here
        console.log('There are ' + someArray.length + ' elements in someArray.');
    }
    cursor.continue();
};
```

Comment: you need to call cursor.continue() here or your cursor will never advance, and you'll never get to the 'Execute code here'

Comment: @alecf Good catch! I am indeed using cursor.continue(), I just forgot to copy it into my post.  I'll add that now.